# PHP search MySQL on multiple tables group by

Tags: php, mysql, search-engine

I am building a search engine where i want to lookup in, for now, two tables. They are not relevant at all.. all i want is to search in both of these tables and export the results..
this is the query i get results, but if a result is found on 'Books' table the output returns a sum of all records on table

```
// explode search words into an array
 $q = $_POST['q'];
 $arraySearch = explode(" ", $q);
 $countSearch = count($arraySearch);
 $b = 0;`

 $query = "SELECT book.title, book.author, store.title, store.address, 
           CONCAT_WS(' ',book.title, book.author, store.title, store.address)
           FROM nt_books book, nt_stores store WHERE (";
  $countFields = count($arrayFields);`

while ($b < $countSearch)
{
  $query = $query."CONCAT_WS(' ',book.title, book.author, store.title, store.address) LIKE '%$arraySearch[$b]%'";
  $b++;
  if ($b < $countSearch)
  {
    $query = $query." AND ";
  }
}
$b = 0;

$query = $query.") AND sem.visible=1
 ORDER BY (
 (
CASE 
    WHEN book.title like '$q%' OR book.author LIKE '$q%' THEN 0
WHEN book.title like '% %$q% %' OR book.title LIKE '% %$q% %' THEN 1
WHEN book.title like '%$q' OR book.title LIKE '%$q' THEN 2
    ELSE 3
    END
)
+(
    CASE WHEN store.title like '$q%' OR store.title LIKE '$q%' THEN 0
    WHEN store.title like '% %$q% %' OR store.title LIKE '% %$q% %' THEN 1
    WHEN store.title like '%$q' OR store.title LIKE '%$q' THEN 1
    ELSE 2
    END
)
 ) DESC";
```

How can i retrieve the results from EACH table seperately? so far, this outputs a mix of all records messed up.

Comment: there´s no chance to do it with a single query. You need 2 select queries for 2 tables, 3 queries for 3 tables, etc. If you change your concept a bit, then maybe you could also use the SQL UNION statement to get all records from 2 different tables as one dataset.

Comment: even if i use 2 queries-2 tables...how could i merge the results and appear in order by relevance..?

Comment: you need to sort it with PHP. First, you need to get all results from all tables in separated arrays. Then, concat it to one huge array with the dataset results of every table. And then you need to sort your huge array by walking through every entry of the array. For comparsion you could use strcmp. If the currenct string is bigger than the last one, it might be after the last pointed string in the array index, and so on.